# How would I be able to scan a CSV file in order to store the values into a HashMap?

Tags: java, csv, hashmap, java.util.scanner

I am trying to scan a CSV file of locations (Ordered: "Location#, Latitude, Longitude") in order to be able to store the values into a HashMap<String, LatLon>; where LatLon is a class I created so that I can store the 2 doubles of Latitude and Longitude for its key (The Location). My issue is that I can't seem to find a way to be able to store these values. I am using a scanner and I tried the following :

```
String path = "fileName.csv";
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(path));

HashMap<String, LatLon> maps = new HashMap<>();


s.useDelimiter(",");

double lat = 0;
double lon = 0;

LatLon latsLons = new LatLon(lat,lon);

while(s.hasNextLine()){
   
   lat = s.nextDouble();
   lon = s.nextDouble();

    maps.put(s.next(),latsLons);
}
        
s.close();
```

I play around with it and try different stuff but to no avail. This case in particular produces an InputMismatchException. Any input on how to deal with this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Your CSV file contains three values per row but you're only reading two.

Comment: If I add String name = s.next and then map.put(name,latsLons) it still displays the error. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

> CSV file of locations (Ordered: "Location#, Latitude, Longitude")

You've a `Location` entry in each line of the file. When you're trying to call s.nextDouble(), the `InputMismatch` occurs as the Location is not double.
You can take the location first calling `s.next()` and then call those two `s.nextDouble()`s.

Also, you can do `String line = s.nextLine()` and `String[] data = line.split(",")` approach. In this way you'll get your location in `data[0]`, lat in `data[1]` and lon in `data[2]` as string.

Answer (score 0):

Define a record to hold your data.

```
record Place ( String location, double latitude , double longitude ) {}
```

Use [`Files.lines`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.charset.Charset)) to read the rows of data from your file as a stream of `String` objects.

Parse each row as *three* values. Your code was parsing only two, and skipping the location. I would use `String#split` to get an array of three strings.

```
String[] fields = line.split( "," ) ;
```

Here is some untested code to get you started.

```
List< Place > places = 
    Files
        .lines( … , … ) 
        .map( 
            line -> 
            {
                String[] fields = line.split( "," ) ;
                Place place = new Place( fields[0] , Double.parseDouble( fields[1] ) , Double.parseDouble( fields[2] ) ) ;
                return place ;
            }
        )
        .toList() ;
```

Now build your map.

```
Map< String , Place > map = new HashMap<>() ;
places.stream().forEach( place -> map.put( place.location() , place ) ;
```